# testing for a fixed number of digits in bash?

Tags: regex, bash

I have a need in a bash script to see if a string ends in an underscore and a date, of the form:

```
   _yyyymmdd
```

I don't care about validating the date at this point, just that I have something like

```
 abc_def_yyyymmdd
```

or

```
 abc_yyyymmdd
```

(Note there may be other underscores in the name that I don't care about;  I only care that it ends in _yyyymmdd  -- an underscore followed by 8 digits).

Can you assist me in that pattern match test?  Let me be clear based on a comment that I don't care about validating the date at this point, just that the string (a filename) ends in an underscore and 8 digits.

Comment: regex won't be used for validating dates.

Comment: what about a number of digits?  I don't want to test for a valid date at this point.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 4):

You may use the below regex,

```
[[ $str =~ _[0-9]{8}$ ]]
```

`[0-9]{8}` would match exactly 8 digit charcaters. `$` asserts that we are at the end.

Comment: The leading `.*` isn't necessary

Comment: I'm updating my cygwin and cannot test at the moment, can you tell me why @chepner?

Comment: The regular expression isn't anchored to the beginning of the string, so the match can start anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the insight.

Comment: oh just saw \d is not recognized by bash.

Comment: Any thought on @tripleee's comment -- at the bottom?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need regex.

```
case $filename in
  *_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] )
    echo "fine";;
  *)
    echo "fail";;
esac
```

Comment: Thanks.  What do you see as an advantage to no-regex vs. using regex?

Comment: Globs are simpler, computationally less expensive, and often (though not in this case) easier to read and debug. Additionally, this `case` construct is  portable all the way back to Unix v7 and the original Bourne shell.

Comment: It's a lot more concise, though, when it's available. If POSIX compatibility is needed, you can use `expr "$filename" : '.*_[0-9]\{8\}$'` (at the expense of starting a new process, of course.)